# ¿Cómo busco los ficheros que empiecen por una letra determinada?

Tags: linux, unix, find

Estoy intentando filtrar archivos por caracteres en el terminal de linux, para ello tengo este arbol de directorios y archivos

```
.  
├── CARPETAS  
│   ├── APUNTES  
│   │   ├── REDES  
│   │   ├── tema1.txt  
│   │   └── tema2.txt  
│   ├── archivo1.txt  
│   ├── archivo2.txt  
│   ├── DOCUMENTOS  
│   │   ├── carta.doc  
│   │   ├── EXCEL  
│   │   ├── plantilla.xls  
│   │   └── WORD  
│   └── PROGRAMAS  
├── lista.txt  
└── procesos.txt
```

Estoy usando para filtrar los archivos que comiencen con los caracteres d y D:

```
sudo ls -r [d,D]*
```

pero el output me arroja:

```
ls: cannot access 'd,D*': No such file or directory
```

Comment: ¿Para qué el sudo? Estás usando bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

intenta asi:

```
find ./ -iname 'd*'
```

Y le antepones `sudo` si hace falta.

`-iname` hace búsqueda sin tener en cuenta mayúscula o minúscula, por lo que al decir `-iname 'd*'` buscará todo aquello que empiece por "D" o "d".

Comment: Funciona a la perfección, muchas gracias